# My computer won't do POST when switched on. Is there a way to determine which component is the culprit without replacement parts?

Tags: boot, troubleshooting

I've taken everything out from the computer there is only the motherboard with the CPU in it. When I switch it on the fans start, but nothing happens. No beeps, no POST.

I guess either the motherboard is faulty or the power supply. I don't have any replacement parts, so I can't replace any of them to test which  one is broken.

Is there a simple way which doesn't require additional tools to determine the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to hear differently, but I believe at this point you need parts to swap in to test now. The only advice I can give is that a new PSU is likely to be the easiest and cheapest to swap out.

Comment: Cheap power supply units are a false economy. I'd try to borrow a spare machine. Might be cheaper to take to a repair shop, as they will have spare parts to hand.

Comment: I brought it to a shop. The motherboard was faulty.